# (Wordpress) Execute plugin if admin is online

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication, admin

### The problem

I have a CHAT plugin for wordpress, I would like it to be active only when administrator (**EDITOR**, to be more precise) is online. When the admin is offline there's no use to have a chat on the website, it only consume space.

### Possible Sulutions

I know little of PHP/Wordpress programming, but I'm almost sure some kind of code in Functions.php might solve the problem, something with **admin_init**, but it has to disable when admin logs off too.

### Conclusion

Desired administration role to activate the plugin: **Editor**

Plugin name: **Online Chat** (online-chat/online-chat.php)

Wordpress Version: **3.4.2**

*Thanks guys!! I'll be around, trying to make it work here too*

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can do a play on this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-info-if-admin-otherwise-hide where if Any user is an admin, then load a template part or trigger an action hook etc. but I haven't tested this myself.

Also check this out: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/checking-if-the-user-is-admin